# (JavaScript) Condition in the replacer parameter in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, if-statement

Why this gives me the properties:

```js
const person = {
  id: 1,
  firstName: 'Jack',
  lastName: 'White',
  age: 25,
};

const json = JSON.stringify(person, (key, value) => typeof(value) == "string" ? undefined : value);

console.log(json);
```

But this gives me 'undefined':

```js
const person = {
  id: 1,
  firstName: 'Jack',
  lastName: 'White',
  age: 25,
};

const json = JSON.stringify(person, (key, value) => typeof(value) == "number" ? value : undefined);

console.log(json);
```

Can't get the differences. Is there a syntax error or just can't works in this way?

Answer (score 0):

This means:

```
typeof(value) == "string" ? undefined : value
```

When a string is found, return undefined. Otherwise, return the original value. So, strings get removed.

This means:

```
typeof(value) == "number" ? value : undefined
```

When a number is found, return that number. Otherwise, return undefined. So, non-numbers get removed. The only value that would produce a result would be a plain number.

```js
const json = JSON.stringify(3, (key, value) => typeof(value) == "number" ? value : undefined);

console.log(json);
```

Perhaps you meant to do

```
typeof value == "number" ? undefined : value
```

removing numbers, but keeping everything else as is.

```js
const person = {
  id: 1,
  firstName: 'Jack',
  lastName: 'White',
  age: 25,
};

const json = JSON.stringify(person, (key, value) => typeof(value) == "number" ? undefined : value);

console.log(json);
```

Or perhaps you meant to remove only non-number *primitives*.

```
typeof value === "object" || typeof value === 'number' ? value : undefined
```

```js
const person = {
  id: 1,
  firstName: 'Jack',
  lastName: 'White',
  age: 25,
};

const json = JSON.stringify(person, (key, value) => typeof value === "object" || typeof value === 'number' ? value : undefined);

console.log(json);
```

Comment: No i was trying to return the property if it value was a number. But can be done only the reverse, that is: *if string* give undefined *other* "give value"... I wanted *if number* "gives value" *other* give "undefined", it is possible?

Comment: The top level that's evaluated is an object, which is not a number, so it gives `undefined`. Yes, that's possible - that's what you're currently doing - but it doesn't really make sense here.

Comment: So when i do:
typeof(value) == "number"
I'm not refering to the actual value of the property? i. e. 1 or 25...

Comment: It goes through the top value first. Here, the top value is an object. An object is not a number, so `undefined` gets returned.

Answer (score 0):

Because the entire **object** is evaluated first, and then each key/value pair. You are denying the **object** first, because it is not a number, so the whole thing is `undefined`. If you match **objects** and **numbers**, it works.

```js
const person = {
  id: 1,
  firstName: 'Jack',
  lastName: 'White',
  age: 25,
};

const json = JSON.stringify(person, (key, value) => (typeof(value) == "number" || typeof(value) == "object") ? value : undefined);

console.log(json);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! But I don't get why it evaluate the entire object first if I'm specifying 'value'. Maybe I don't get how the replacer parameter actually works? Also with the or operator you refered both to the object and value with the same parameter('value'), how it is possible? Sorry if they are really basic questions but I started studying js for 1-2 months.

Comment: It evaluates the entire expression first. If the expression is an object, it then evaluates each property. If one of those properties is an object, it evaluates all of that object's properties, and so on. The parameter `value` just refers to the current value of the thing it's evaluating (when it's evaluating the whole object, the `value` refers to the whole object, and the `key` is an empty string).